# What is the best perl module to extract text from a pdf?

Tags: perl, pdf, text, extract

What is the best way to extract text from a pdf?

Comment: similar question perhaps useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139015/how-can-i-do-a-full-text-search-of-pdf-files-from-perl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CAM%3a%3aPDF) module is pretty useful for extracting text and maintaining some information about where it came from in the document. It installs /usr/local/bin/getpdftext.pl which demonstrates simple extraction. However, CAM::PDF can only read PDFs that are completely valid.

If you are dealing with ill-formed PDFs, you may need a more lenient parser, such as pdftotext. It dumps foo.pdf to foo.txt, which you could then read into Perl.

Comment: Nice first post!  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks. It's nice to earn privileges such as posting two links at the same time. :)