# Is there a way to do a text search within a specific area of a PDF using Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf

I have PDF's created by PDFcreator.  The first page of each multipage PDF has the mailing address that needs to be identified.  Is there a way to do a text search within a specific area of a PDF?

I have found [CAM::PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049486/is-it-possible-to-read-the-text-in-a-pdf-file-using-perl) and [pdftotext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139015/how-can-i-do-a-full-text-search-of-pdf-files-from-perl), but don't see a way to limit the search to a specific area.  My primary concern is accuracy, because there is a chance a different address may appear in the same PDF.  Also searching the entire PDF is probably too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Pdftotext can indeed accomplish what you want to do.  I am fairly sure CAM::PDF can as well, but I haven't used that tool to return coordinate information in the past.

I would run pdftotext on the entire page, save the xml output, and then comb through the results.  It should give you xMin/xMax/yMin/yMax values for every word on the page. You can then use those coordinates to build a list of only those words that fall within your pre-determined boundaries.

Smoothly identifying a multiline address may present its own challenges however, especially if there could be any non-address text within your defined area.

Comment: How do you get pdftotext to output the xMin/xMax/yMin/yMax ??

Comment: When you run it, pipe the output to an xml file, eg: pdftotext input.pdf output.txt >xml_output.xml